# Program Freezes in Socket Programming in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I made this program of Server and Client But Program Freezes.I deleted the DataInputStream from server Program.Then it works Fine

Server program:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Server2
{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9900);
    System.out.println("Waiting For Client to Connect");
    Socket s=ss.accept();
    System.out.println("connection established");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter string:");
    String p=sc.nextLine();
    DataOutputStream d=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    d.writeBytes(p);

    System.out.println("String Swaped character!!!");
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Break");
    System.out.println(in.readUTF());
    d.close();
    in.close();

}
}
```

Client Program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Client2
{
public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
{
    Socket s=new Socket("LocalHost",9900);
    DataInputStream d2=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    String r=d2.readLine();
    DataOutputStream out= new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF(r);

    d2.close();
    System.out.println(r);


   }
}
```

I have Made Many similar Programs But Didn't face any problem like this.Can anyone please help me with whats Wrong.Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: did you make sure,that the string received by the client (variable r) is terminated by '\n' or '\r' ?

Comment: yes I added +"\n" in writeBytes on server side and it worked..thanks ,but I don't understand the reason of doing so..can you  explain?

Comment: Sure, the `readLine()` of the DataInputStream is a blocking method, which means that the whole thread will be blocked until a result is received ( almost every IO operation has a similar behaviour) .This means the we are stuck. '\n' is the 'new line'character which indicates that a new line , what the readLine method does is that is bufferes characters until '\n' "new line" or '\r' "carriage return" arrives

Comment: Thanks alot that helped :)